# Program to Check If string is Palindrome (in C)

Tags: beginner, c, strings, palindrome

Just wrote a program to check if a string is Palindrome. If that's true, return 1. Else, return 0. How can I improve it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int palindrome(char *s)
{
    int i = 0, length = strlen(s) - 1, n = length;
    int boolean = 0;

    for (; i <= length && n >= 0; i++, n--) {
        if (toupper(s[i]) == toupper(s[n]))
            boolean = 1;
        else
            boolean = 0;
    }

    return boolean;
}

int main(void)
{
    char string[] = "Racecar";

    printf("%d", palindrome(string));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because I posted [a similar snippet](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/112401/palindromes-in-c) myself, I can tell you that this general approach doesn't work with multi-byte encodings e.g. UTF-8, because a two-byte character would be read second-half first when going right-to-left. Just something to think about.

Comment: The code is obviously broken.

Comment: Can you test, please, the value of `palindrome("dead") `...?

Comment: You might consider removing all the spaces from a string before doing the palindrome test.  The user could accidentally enter a space before or after a word, and there are palindrome sentences that you might want to validate (_Euston saw I was not Sue_) and spaces don't count in that case.  Plus, it's extra practice:  What's the easiest way to remove all occurrences of a given character (space) from a string?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Bug

Given the input `"racebar"`, the function returns true.  The problem is that your boolean variable is reset after each character pair, so you are only really testing the first character with the last.  I would do the following:

1. Get rid of the boolean variable and return false on the first mismatch.
2. Fix the loop iteration to only iterate through half the string instead of the whole string.
3. Mark the input parameter as `const`, since you do not modify the input string.  This allows your function to accept both const strings and non-const string as arguments.
4. In C99, you can declare loop variables inside the loop itself, which helps to reduce the scope of these variables to only where they are used.

Here is a rewrite showing all of the above:

```
int palindrome(const char *s)
{
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(s) - 1; i < n; i++, n--) {
        if (toupper(s[i]) != toupper(s[n]))
            return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Any reason for still defining `i` ahead of the loop? It's never used anywhere outside.

Comment: @Zano Because unless anyone says otherwise, I always assume C89.

Comment: Why don't you initialize `i` inside the for loop like so `for (i = 0;` instead of doing it outside and then doing `for (;`?

Comment: @BoristheSpider You can set i = 0 inside a for loop in C89 just not declare it int i = 0

Comment: @Insane I see your point. I'm being stupid - ignore me.

Comment: Thanks, I honestly had no idea this wasn't possible until C99. I actually taught myself ANSI C with K&R 2nd edition way back when, but It's been a really long time...

Comment: @Zano and JS1: I'd certainly suggest C99 syntax when it brings readability improvements.  Questions that need compatibility with an ancient version of the language should ask for it (or just not adopt any recommendations that they can't use with C89).  gcc 5 finally changed the default to compile C99 if you don't use any `-std` option.  (The default is now `-std=gnu11`, which is C11 with GNU extensions, not just C99).  I'm sure there are still some niche C89-only compilers for microcontrollers and stuff, but actively avoiding C99's better syntax is silly 16 years later.

Comment: To all: I added a C99 version by popular demand.  To me it's not a given that C99 is being used because I actually deal with C89 code a lot.  So if I don't see any C99 features being used in the existing code, my natural instinct is to not add any C99 features to the code.  I'll keep in mind that not everyone knows about C99 features, so in the future, I will suggest using them if they improve the code.

Comment: The function doesn't create or find a palindrome, but rather tests if the input is a palindrome – so I'd like to see it named e.g. `testPalindrome` or, even better, `isPalindrome`.

Comment: Also consider including `<stdbool.h>` and returning a `bool` instead of an `int` (assuming C99).

Answer (score 6):

**Main suggestion**

I would actually say `length = strlen(s)` instead of `length = strlen(s) - 1`.

This way, the variable's name reflects the variable's contents. For instance, `strlen("abc")` is 3, so it is counter-intuitive to set `length` to 2!

Of course you then need to set `n = length - 1` and change your comparison to `i < length`. This is a very natural way to do things in C. The following is a very common pattern:

```
int i;
int num_items = 5;

for (i = 0; i < num_items; i++) {
    //will loop 5 times
}
```

**Minor suggestions**

- Consider renaming `i` and `n` to something more meaningful like `left` and `right`
- Use constants for true and false to make your code easier to understand at a glance

  ```
  #define TRUE 1
  #define FALSE 0

  //then you can return TRUE; or return FALSE;
  ```
- Use assertions for quick and easy testing:

  ```
  #include <assert.h>

  ...

  void testPalindrome() {
      assert(palindrome("") == TRUE);
      assert(palindrome("a") == TRUE);
      assert(palindrome("aA") == TRUE);
      assert(palindrome("ab") == FALSE);
      assert(palindrome("aba") == TRUE);
      assert(palindrome("aab") == FALSE);
      assert(palindrome("Abba") == TRUE);
      //add several more
      //try to think of cases that are likely to produce
      //false positive or false negative results
  }

  int main(void)
  {
      testPalindrome();

      //put the rest of your code here
      ...
  }
  ```

  This way as you make changes or improvements to your code, your tests will automatically run each time you run your program and you will notice if you accidentally break something. It also encourages you to think about how your function is actually supposed to behave. (E.g. is "" actually a palindrome? What about examples containing non-letters?)

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! GOod job on your first answers.

Answer (score 0):

As JS1 said, the code returns `true` for "racebar". That's because your code sets `boolean` to `false` when it sees that 'b', but overwrites it with `true` with the next 'a'.

I'd suggest some things:

- Don't use `boolean` as a name. There's a `bool` keyword in C++ for Boolean variables and `boolean` keyword in Java. Use something that indicates the contents - such as `isPalindrome`. Same goes for `char string[]`; use something like `str` instead.
- You don't need both `i` and `n` - due to the simple reason that the length of the string never changes. When it will change, you will need two variables to keep track of the front and back. (You'll see this when you learn about linked lists).
- To get over the overwriting problem, use `break`. It'll get you out of the `for` loop as soon as you detect that 'b', so you can return a `false` right away.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

int checkPalindrome(char * input);

int main()
{
    int res = checkPalindrome("racebar");
    if(res) printf("True\n");
    else printf("False\n");  /* this is printed */
    return 0; /* don't need this if void main()*/
}

int checkPalindrome(char * input)
{
    int i, length = strlen(input), isPal = TRUE;
    for(i = 0; i < length/2; i++)
    {
        if(input[i] != input[length - 1 - i])
        {
            isPal = FALSE;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isPal;
}
```

- I've used a declaration, as I've written the `checkPalindrome()` method after `main()`. It's not needed in your case, but it's a good practice to write it regardless.
- My code does not check for lower and uppercase. To add that functionality, I'd also simply call `toUpper()`.
- A small optimization I've done is to only iterate through half the string. If it's odd, the middle character doesn't need to be checked anyway.
- By default, `isPal` is set to `TRUE`. If the string is a palindrome, the loop exits normally and `TRUE` is returned. Otherwise, `break` exits the loop abruptly and `FALSE` is returned.

Answer (score -1):

When you mentally check a word to see if it's a palindrome do you first compare the letters at each end and work inwards letter by letter or do you just read the word backwards and compare to the original word? I do the latter so modelling that you could just reverse the word and compare to the original.

Comment: That's a sub-optimal approach to the problem. That means creating multiple copies of the string and doing a bunch of work that doesn't need to be done.

Comment: That would require preparing a reversed *copy* of the input, and then comparing it to the original. The latter requires the same amount of work as comparing letter by letter from both ends toward the midpoint, so the former is a pure waste of effort.